# doGet() is not implemented by this URL

Tags: http, servlets

In my servlet I used doPost() method and while running the servlet it is giving http method doGet is not supported by this url.And  I set 
POST
GET in my web.xml under .Still getting the method doGet() not implemented.
Some times giving me doPost() is not supported by this URL.
How to resolve these?

Comment: Follow the stacktrace file:linenumber and you will find!

Answer (score 1):

check the `doGet()` and `doPost()` implementation for your servlet, looks like you just created a setvlet and IDE added a basic template method which throws an unimplemented exception